# How to get field from hashtable object

Tags: c#, hashtable, unity-game-engine

i have a problem here to get the field from hastable object. here what i have:

i have  a unity c# function

```
void completionHandler( string error, object result )
{
    debug.log(result.GetType); // the type of result is System.Collections.Hastable 
}
```

is there anyway to get the field from result;
what i have tried:

1. Didn't show anything

   ```
   FieldInfo[] fields = result.GetType().GetFields();
   foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in fields)
   {
     Debug.Log("Obj, Field: " + fieldInfo.Name);
   }
   ```
2. Also didn't show anything:

   ```
   Hashtable resultHash = result.toHashtable();
   foreach (string keys in resultHash.Keys)
   {
     Debug.Log("Obj, keys: " + keys);
   }
   ```

Comment: What do you mean by "the field"? Your question is very unclear. Is there any reason you're using `Hashtable` to start with, rather than `Dictionary<,>`?

Comment: @JonSkeet the problem is i can't change the result type. because that is what i get from the plugin. the field what i mean is something like result["field1"]

Comment: Well if using `resultHash.Keys` doesn't give you anything, it sounds like it's empty... (You still haven't explained what you mean by "the field".)

Comment: A `Hashtable` has no fields!

Comment: What is "the field"? What are you trying to get?

Comment: And also can you give definition of ".toHashtable"?

Comment: i mean DictionaryEntry, here is the case. i'm trying to build android app, and i buy a plugin for unity, that have some code in c#. in the plugin code they have some logging system it self. when completionhandler running it logging/show a DictionaryEntry from result object in a logcat. so what i want is how to get that DictionaryEntry and use it. sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's very hard to understand what is being asked. 
Here is a piece of code that explains the code snippets you provided:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Reflection;

namespace SO14577299
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            object result = new Hashtable();
            //Trying to get public fields via reflection:
            //there are no public fields on this class
            FieldInfo[] fields = result.GetType().GetFields();
            foreach (FieldInfo fieldInfo in fields)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Obj, Field: " + fieldInfo.Name);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("->1");

            Hashtable resultHash = result as Hashtable;
            //Trying to list all the keys
            //this is an empty collection, nothing there
            foreach (string keys in resultHash.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Obj, keys: " + keys);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("->2");

            resultHash = new Hashtable();
            resultHash["a"] = "1";
            resultHash["b"] = "2";
            //Trying to list all the keys
            //Now there are two: a and b
            foreach (string keys in resultHash.Keys)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Obj, keys: " + keys);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("->3");
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the output of this code:

```
->1
->2
Obj, keys: a
Obj, keys: b
->3
```

The first output is empty because you are trying to enumerate public fields of the Hashtable class: there are none.

The second output is empty, simply because hash table is empty.
The third output demonstrate what is being printed if the output is not empty.

You can try to debug your code by trying to output the count:

```
foreach (string keys in resultHash.Keys)
{
  Debug.Log("Count: " + resultHash.Count.ToString());
}
```

This way you can prove/disprove that your hashtable is empty.

Also please check the `toHashtable` method. It's not a standard method, and there is no telling from your example what it might do. It can do something very different from what one would expect. If you know that the object is of hashtable type, `Hashtable resultHash = result as Hashtable` is a safer bet

Comment: i use your second output in my code. and all it works. thank's for your explanation sir. with this all is clear. best regard, andre

Comment: @andre as you are new to StackOverflow, I'd like to let you know that you should upvote the answers that helped you and mark a single answer as the answer. Thanks.

Comment: it seems i must have 15 reputation to vote up a answer. how to mark answer as the answer?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the object to a `Hashtable` and then parse it, you may try this:

```
void completionHandler(string error, object result)
{
    var hashTable = result as Hashtable;
    if (hashTable != null)
    {
        foreach (object key in hashTable.Keys)
        {
            Debug.Write(
                String.Format("key:{0} value:{1}", 
                    key.ToString(), 
                    hashTable[key]));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oh man, that exactly what i looking for. thank's alot man. you're my savior.